# find exact match for string with RegExp

Tags: c#, regex, string, winforms

I´m trying to do some code that haves a string(ing) and a string array (splitwords).
I need to run a string and if it matches the string from the string array does something with that original string.

```
StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();

          ing = " " + ing + " ";

          builder.Append(@"{\rtf1\ansi");

          foreach (string word in splitwords)
          {

              if (Regex.IsMatch(ing, @"(?<![\w])" + word + @"(?![\w])"))
              {
                  //do domething
              }

          builder.Append(ing);
          builder.Append(@"}");


          return builder.ToString();
```

It runs ok, but if the word to match is "leite" and in the text it has the word "leitelho" he thinks it´s a match.
How can I change my if condition to solve this problem?

Comment: how `(?<!\w)leite(?!\w)` matches `leite` in `leitelho`

Comment: @Avinash Raj. It shouldn't match but it does.. That´s qhy I´m asking for help.

Answer (score 1):

you can use this code and I choses original in place of ing:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
        string original = "leite";
        string[] splitwords = new string[] { "leitelho", "leite", "One" };

        original = " " + original + " ";

        builder.Append(@"{\rtf1\ansi");

        foreach (string word in splitwords)
        {

            if (Regex.IsMatch(original, @"(?<![\w])" + word + @"(?![\w])"))
            {
                //do domething
                builder.Append(original);
                builder.Append(@"}");
                Console.Write(builder.ToString());
                return;
            }
       }
    }
```

Comment: It may work just for the word "leite" and for others ??

Comment: sure you can use what you want.